# Flutter: SQFLite database is not showing data in application

Tags: flutter, sqflite, sqlite-journal-mode

In my Android application, I need to add about 300 customers. As application have database `import/export` feature available so I decided to do insert customers on computer, instead of mobile.

Here's how I did that:

1. Install app on mobile
2. Exported `db` using export feature
3. Inserted data using SQLite Editor tool
4. Saved the DB
5. Transferred on mobile and imported back

Logically, it should work but it's not working.

**Export/Import Feature:**

This feature does work as expected, I've tested like this:

1. Added some dummy data
2. Exported data on SD card
3. Delete the App
4. Re-install (dummy data wasn't available)
5. Imported data back and it worked

**What I noticed:**

1. The exported database zip file contains a file with same name as database but with an additional word e.g `DBNAME.db-journal`. When I added data in `db` using SQLite Editor, and save it. The `-journal` file was removed.
2. As application doesn't show added data in app, but if we export `db` from app and open it in editor, then it shows all data.

I've even tried to remove previous `-journal` file, right before importing but no luck.

Comment: `"SQFLite database is not showing data in application"` post the relevant code of that application

Comment: There's a lot of code, it won't be easy for anyone to just make it work because it depends on a lot of classes, libraries and I can't share entire app code. Please tell me, which part of code should I share?

Comment: where you use [query](https://pub.dev/documentation/sqflite/latest/sqlite_api/DatabaseExecutor/query.html) method

Comment: There are a lot of `db.query` statements, here is a sample statement which gets cities. `await db.query('cities',
            where: 'state = ?', whereArgs: [state], orderBy: 'name ASC')`

Comment: I'd have looked into the sqflite source code to see exactly what files are being written and read from.

Comment: @ZeekHuge I don't understand; what exactly you need. I've already mentioned, the Import/Export feature works as expected, but the problem occur, when we export database and modify using any other tool. In other words, when the `.db-journal` file is not available.

Comment: actually i am lost, what is your problem actually? your app opens your database but it is empty (even if you see some data using `sqlite3` tool)? what you see if you enter `.dump` command using `sqlite3` (lets say, first 10 lines)?

Comment: should I run that command on mobile OR machine and how? (any example) I was using GUI based tool called "DB Browser for SQLite"